# Should a library explicitly target .NET Core 3?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core-3.0

With the release of .NET Standard 2.0, it's advised to target .NET Standard 2.0, even if you target 1.x already.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard:

> However, targeting lower .NET Standard versions introduces a number of support dependencies. If your project targets .NET Standard 1.x, we recommend that you also target .NET Standard 2.0. This simplifies the dependency graph for users of your library that run on .NET Standard 2.0 compatible frameworks, and it reduces the number of packages they need to download.

Now another big change is near! .NET Core 3 and I see that Microsoft **also** is targeting .NET Core 3 for Microsoft packages.

For example, [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/3.0.0-preview9.19423.4) is targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and also .NET Core 3 (.NETCoreApp 3.0):

[image]

I compared the XML files and both APIs look the same (maybe not the best way to compared them)

Now the question ;)

As a library maintainer that depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, who trying to support .NET Core 3:
Should I also target .NET Core 3 - or is just .NET Standard 2.0 good enough if I don't need specific stuff of .NET Core 3?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

You don't have to target .NET Core 3 if you don't want to use anything from it, or if you don't want to offer any .NET Core 3 optimizations. On the other hand, double targeting doesn't cost you anything and may allow you to get rid of library references that are now built into .NET Core 3. At the very least you may be able to get rid of some library references that now come with the runtime.

**Long answer**

It depends entirely on what you're doing, what you want to do. A library doesn't *have* to target .NET Core 3.0 just because its dependencies include it in their targets.

For example, [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Logging/Logging/src)  shows that `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` doesn't seem to have any C# 8/.NET Core 3.0 specific code. It targets 3.0 because it's part of that wave of extensions, so double-targeting doesn't require any modifications.

On the other hand, [Config.Json](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Configuration/Config.Json/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.csproj) doesn't have to reference `System.Text.Json` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` because they are part of the runtime.

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

*Other benefits*

For maintainers, .NET Core 3.0/.NET Standard 2.1 offer a *lot* of sanity preserving features like:

- Nullable Reference Types. You'll avoid a lot of NREs in your own code. You'll probably catch a lot of hidden bugs too.
- Default interface members. You won't have to worry about breaking users' code when you add a new member to a public interface.
- IAsyncEnumerable. No more waiting for all results from a bunch of asynchronous operations
- The switch expression and far more powerfull pattern matching and deconstruction syntax.

For some of those features you can add only a few methods that will be available only for .NET Core. For example, the [ChannelReader class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs) adds a single `ReadAllAsync()` method in a partial file that reads items from a channel and returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<>`, eg :

```
    public virtual async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ReadAllAsync([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        while (await WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            while (TryRead(out T item))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a small but *very* convenient addition. It allows you to receive messages with :

```
await foreach(var msg from reader.ReadAllAsync())
{
   ....
}
```

NRTs on the other hand will help even for .NET Standard 2.0 because they help you catch nullability bugs in the source code when compiling for .NET Core 3.0.

Comment: But the benefits are not there is I need to target also older platforms? I assume I can't use c#8 syntax for (also targeting) .net standard 2.0

Comment: @Julian I posted an example of how you *can*. In any case, if you *don't* want to target .NET Core 3, you don't have to. The Logging library doesn't force you to do so

Comment: Ok. But unfortunately this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Julian what is the question and what do you expect the answer to look like? You don't *have* to target .NET Core 3 even if one of your dependencies includes it in its targets. If you don't want anything from .NET Core 3, you don't *need* to target it

Answer (score 2):

> *As a library maintainer that dependents on*
>   *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, who trying to support .NET Core 3:*
>   *Should I also target .NET Core 3 - or is just .NET Standard 2.0 good*
>   *enough if I don't need specific stuff of .NET Core 3?*

**Targeting .NET Standard 2.0 in your library is good enough for as long as all of your dependencies target .NET Standard 2.0 as well, including `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`**.

As [Panagiotis Kanavos said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911030/211672), there can be benefits of targeting .NET Core 3.0 for the consumers of your library, so if that's the case and it doesn't cost you too much, then by all means target .NET Core 3.0 in addition to .NET Standard 2.0.

As [karann said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914968/211672), nuget will always select the best matching assets for every package in the graph. i.e.

- App A uses your library and targets .NET Core 3.0. Your library targets .NET Standard 2.0 only. NuGet will use that, and it's fine.
- App A uses your library and targets .NET Core 3.0. Your library targets both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 3.0. NuGet will choose .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Is there any reason to target `.NET Core 3.0` rather than `.NET Standard 2.1`?

Answer (score 0):

When someone installs a package, NuGet uses the assets from TFM that best matches the TFM of the project. It does this for the transitive dependencies too.

For example - if the project target netcore30 and package A has assets under lib/netcore30 and lib/netstandard20, nuget will select lib/netcore30. Let's say package A depends on B, and package B has assets for netstandard20, net472, nuget will select netstandard20.

Bottom line is, nuget will select the best matching assets for every package in the graph. So, as a library maintainer, you don't need to add two TFMs to support netcore30. You can target netstandard21 which implies support for netcore30 based on this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Unfortunately this won't answer why Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is targeting netstandard2.0  + netcore3.0 and what a dependent library should do.

Comment: @Julian a dependent library doesn't *have* to support .NET Core 3 if it doesn't want to. People building applications in .NET Core 2.1 or .NET Framework 4.8 that use  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging get the latest NuGet package every time they upgrade packages without having to switch to .NET Core 3

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question.