# Microsoft.Extensions.* version confusion

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a library targeting `netstandard2.0` that I use in a `ASP.NET Core 2.2` application that relies on a couple of `Microsoft.Extensions` packages

Here is my `csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I now want to be able to use this same library in a new `ASP.NET Core 3` application as well as my existing `ASP.NET Core 2.2` applications.

Looking at the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages, their versions always appear to match the release versions of `ASP.NET Core`.

My options are

- Do nothing .. Will this package still work in an `ASP.NET Core 3` application?
- Upgrade the packages to their `3.0` equivalents .. Will this package still work in an `ASP.NET Core 2` application?
- Keep the existing package (for `ASP.NET Core 2.2` applications), but create a new package using the `3.0` equivalents for use in `ASP.NET Core 3.0` applications

The overall question is as a library author, what is the correlation between a specific version of a `Microsoft.Extensions.*` package and its use within a specific `ASP.NET Core` target?

Comment: I've a related question posted before, it's unclear to me also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846163/should-a-library-explicitly-target-net-core-3

Comment: Thanks Julian, will check it out .. all this targeting is super confusing to me, glad I'm not alone

Comment: For those who come to this question a little later, and you are trying to use the Microsoft.Extensions (maybe Configuration) in a _.NetStandard 2.1_ library this is still even more confusing. Microsoft.Extensions targets either .NetStandard 2.0 _OR_ .NetCoreApp 3.1. So VS tells you _'Can't use this for .NetStandard 2.1. Make it a .netcore application'_, which might have a domino affect on other standard libraries you are writing. The confusion is because Visual Studio doesn't tell you '_or you can target .NetStandard 2.0 and be just fine - maybe even reach more users than with 2.1_'.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) do multi-targeting.

Target `netstandard2.0` and `netstandard2.1`, for `netstandard2.0` reference the 2.x (lowest one which works for you, prob 2.0, there should be no breaking changes in 2.x) and for `netstandard2.1` reference the 3.x versions of it.

#### Why?

Because its a major version jump, usually ending up with new apis, removal of old or change of method signatures (in other words: breaking changes) and since `netstandard2.1` requires .NET Core 3.0 so also applications referencing it rely on `Microsoft.Extensions.*` 3.x version APi surface

To conditionally reference a package, do

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0"/>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1' ">
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Alternatively

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0" Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.01' "/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0" Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1' "/>
```

works too, but its less readable. This will still create one NugetPackage, but it will have two folders `netstandard2.0` and `netstandard2.1` with two separately complied assemblies targeting the different versions.

When this package is restored on .NET Core 3, it will use the `netstandard2.1` version, if restored on .NET Core 2.x it will use `netstandard2.0`.

If there are api differences, you have to use preprocessor directives in your code

```
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
    // API call of 2.x library
#elif NETSTANDARD2_1
    // Api call of 3.x library
#endif
```

Comment: Taking the example of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. Version v3.0 adds some additional members (https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/3.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/diff/2.2.0/) AND targets netstandard 2.0. If I took the approach you suggest then the additional functionality would only be available when referenced by `NET Core 3` when it could in fact be made available for all netstandard 2.0 targets. So in that case targeting `netstandard2.0` and using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0"` seems like the best of both worlds. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 1):

with reference to your options:

> Do nothing .. Will this package still work in an ASP.NET Core 3 application?

Can't give exact answer, it depends on the classes availability in the target framework, you may check in [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/) for all .NET versions

> Upgrade the packages to their 3.0 equivalents .. Will this package still work in an ASP.NET Core 2 application?

No, when you target a higher version it will try to install all related dependencies from the higher versioned framework as well, and this will make a lot of confusion.

> Keep the existing package (for ASP.NET Core 2.2 applications), but create a new package using the 3.0 equivalents for use in ASP.NET Core 3.0 applications

This can solve the issue but it is not a practical solution, you will double the work when you work on any updates.

As mentioned in the previous comment, you can do multiple target nuget package (consider this option only if you need framework specific dependencies)

@Tseng already explained the conditional targeting, I will add only the targeting for .NET Core 3, since most of the [nuget packages are already included in the core 3 framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) you may only need to add framework reference as below:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.0'">
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.0.0" Exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
</ItemGroup>
```